# PHP script for accepting a form submitted from iPhone

Tags: php, iphone, objective-c, uiimagepickercontroller

Hi I'm using this sample to upload a photo into my server [Objective C: How to upload image and text using HTTP POST?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5422028/objective-c-how-to-upload-image-and-text-using-http-post)

However, I fail to grab parameter1 and parameter2 using $_POST or $_REQUEST

`NSString *param1 = @"parameter text";
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"parameter1\"\r\n\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:param1] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:@"\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];`

Is there something else I need to use aside from $_POST and $_REQUEST to grab the parameters?

Answer (score 0):

Try the following :

```
-(void) httpRequestSender{
    NSString *par1 = @"test1";
    NSString *par2 = @"test2";
    NSString *requestedURL=@"http://something/post.php";
    NSString *urlString =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@?par1=%@&par2=%@",requestedURL,par1,par2];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:url];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"GET"];

    NSURLResponse *response = nil;
    NSError *error = nil;
    NSData *result = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request
        returningResponse:&response error:&error];
    NSString *resultString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:result encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    //resultString is the returned buffer from calling the page
[request release];

}
```