# iOS - POST an image to server by Resty

Tags: iphone, ios, rest, http-headers

I used [this method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/937475/928315) to POST an image to server before, but it's a little complicated because I have to add header and boundary by myself. Yesterday I found a project called [Resty](http://projects.lukeredpath.co.uk/resty/) - "A simple Objective-C HTTP client for iOS and Mac". However, after reading all of its documents, I can't find any method to upload an image file. Please help, thanks so much.

```
NSMutableDictionary *params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
[params setObject:@"this is a title" forKey:@"title"];

// ***How can I add an image by Resty?***
[params setObject:UIImageJPEGRepresentation(self.image, 1.0) forKey:@"image"];

LRRestyClient *client = [LRResty client];
[client setUsername:userId password:userToken];
[client post:APIImageUrl payload:params withBlock:^(LRRestyResponse *response){
    NSLog(@"Done");
}];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think this framework not handle image data and custom parameters correctly you may follow this topic and create correct NSData format

[How to upload image and text using HTTP POST?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5422028/objective-c-how-to-upload-image-and-text-using-http-post)

or if you want more mature framework personally i advice restkit.
in my project i send image to rest service with this sample code

```
 RKObjectManager *service = restkit_manager; //initialized previously
      [service loadObjectsAtResourcePath:@"/api/ChangeProfileImage" usingBlock:^(RKObjectLoader *loader) {
            loader.delegate      = self;
            loader.method        = RKRequestMethodPOST;
            loader.cachePolicy   = RKRequestCachePolicyNone;
            loader.objectMapping = (RKObjectMapping *) [service.mappingProvider mappingForKeyPath:MAPPING_PROFILE_IMAGE_UPDATE];

            NSMutableDictionary *params_dict = [NSMutableDictionary new];

           //custom parameters
           [params_dict setValue:UserKey forKey:@"UserKey"];

            RKParams *params = [RKParams paramsWithDictionary:params_dict];
            //encoded image
            [params setData:data MIMEType:@"image/png" forParam:@"FileName"];

            loader.params                = params;
            loader.serializationMIMEType = RKMIMETypeJSON;
        }];
```

this slide may give idea http://www.slideshare.net/tkalapun/restfull-with-restkit

Answer (score 0):

I use [ASIHTTPRequest](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/How-to-use), which is very simple and powerful.
I think using this library is another choice.

My sample code is...

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://endpoint"];
NSData *data = [self addMetadata:UIImageJPEGRepresentation(self.image, 1.0)];

ASIFormDataRequest *request = [ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:url];
[ASIFormDataRequest setDefaultTimeOutSeconds:90];
[ASIFormDataRequest setShouldThrottleBandwidthForWWAN:YES];

[request setNumberOfTimesToRetryOnTimeout:3];
[request setAllowCompressedResponse:NO];

[request setData:data withFileName:@"photo.jpg" andContentType:@"image/jpeg" forKey:@"image"];
[request startSynchronous];
```