# How to send a image from iOS to web service

Tags: ios, image, web-services

I want to upload an image to a webservice from iOS. In web service image parameter datatype is `File`. I want to send a thumb of a image that user taking from his phone camera. Can anyone says how to send a thumb image from iOS app to a web service.

Thanks.

Comment: I imagine it would involve a POST request.  Without a **far** more specific question though, no one will be able to be more detailed.

Comment: I want to know the way to upload the image using POST request.

Comment: I already convert it into base64 format,,, but what should I do further from that point

Comment: @iDia Did you look at the answer to the question above?  It seems to have exactly what you want.

Comment: There is already a duplicate question on this topic http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5422028/objective-c-how-to-upload-image-and-text-using-http-post You might find this link helpful too. http://insanelycrazy.net/development/faces/viewarticle.xhtml?id=6

Comment: yes I checked but I can't understand what is that boundary variable. Do I need to send all parameters of that particular link according to POST? or only the image should send in  POST way?

Answer (score 4):

With `AFNetworking` you can do it by:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"my_base_url"];
AFHTTPClient *httpClient = [[AFHTTPClient alloc] initWithBaseURL:url];
NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation([UIImage imageNamed:@"yourImage.jpg"], 0.5);
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [httpClient multipartFormRequestWithMethod:@"POST" path:@"/upload" parameters:nil constructingBodyWithBlock: ^(id <AFMultipartFormData>formData) {
    [formData appendPartWithFileData:imageData name:@"MainMedia" fileName:@"MainMedia" mimeType:@"image/jpeg"];
}];

AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:request];
[operation setUploadProgressBlock:^(NSInteger bytesWritten, long long totalBytesWritten, long long totalBytesExpectedToWrite) {
    NSLog(@"Sent %lld of %lld bytes", totalBytesWritten, totalBytesExpectedToWrite);
}];

[operation start];
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are using `ASIHttpRequest` Library look at this code:

```
ASIFormDataRequest *request = [ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:yourRequestURL]];

[request addRequestHeader:@"User-Agent" value:@"ASIHTTPRequest"]; 
[request addRequestHeader:@"Content-Type" value:@"application/json"];

NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSCachesDirectory,     NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *savedImagePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@/%@",[paths objectAtIndex:0],folder,imageName];

if ([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:savedImagePath])
    [request setFile:savedImagePath forKey:@"imgfile"];
[request setRequestMethod:@"POST"];
[request setDelegate:self];
[request setDidFailSelector:@selector(requestFailed:)];
```

I hope it will help you.

Comment: You can do it by AFNetwork Library also.