# I want to use Face Detect API of HpCloud for iphone sdk

Tags: php, ios, iphone, face-detection

We can use face detect in two ways:
1. by passing url
2. by uploading image.

I need to use 2nd one.

I got the code in php like

> ```
> <form action="path_to_facedetect" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
>     <input type="file" id="pic" name="pic" />
>     <input type="text" id="url_object_store" name="url_object_store" />
>     <input type="submit" value="Send it..." />
> </form>
> ```

from the link:
http://map.hpl.hp.com/face-detection/api.html

Can any one tell me how to pass data in iPhone?

I need to pass:

1.url_object_store
2.X-Auth-Token
3.bytes array of image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tried another way to solve it...

create link with URL_Object_Store and pass both "Link" and "URL_Object_Store" in URL, and pass file (bytes array) in body part, to the object storage API of HP.

The object is created now.then pass that created object's link to Face detection API

Answer (score 1):

Create the post request and pass data like [this](http://iphonediscussionforam.blogspot.in/2012/04/upload-image-on-server-in-objective-c.html)
or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5422028/objective-c-how-to-upload-image-and-text-using-http-post) link from iphone.

Another way i will suggest that encode your image in base64 string and send it with post request from iphone. Decode the same string from php webservice to create image and store it to server.

Comment: Thanks, but i have already tried this.I need to know how to pass which argument, exactly... I m getting "Incorrect Arguments" error.